# Classes with @cond are showing when HIDE_UNDOC_MEMBERS is set to YES

Tags: c#, doxygen

I have the follow lines set in my .doxy file:

```
EXTRACT_ALL            = NO
HIDE_UNDOC_MEMBERS     = YES
HIDE_UNDOC_CLASSES     = YES
```

My c# classes have this structure:

```
public class Foo {
    public Bar bar { get; set; }
    ...
}

// @cond Beta
public class Bar {
        ...
}
// @endcond
```

Beta is not being set in the ENABLED_SECTIONS line.

The problem here is that the bar property is showing on the page for Foo. The @cond annotation is effective in suppressing Bar from having its own page, therefore shouldn't Bar be considered "undocumented" and hidden from Foo's page due to the HIDE_UNDOC_MEMBERS set to YES?

Results of doxygen -x:

```
C:\Users\mille>doxygen -x "D:\Company\Sandbox\Proj9.4\Proj\Api.DocGenerator\doxy\Proj API.doxy"
# Difference with default Doxyfile 1.8.15
PROJECT_NAME           = "Proj API"
PROJECT_BRIEF          = "Web services for communicating with Proj"
PROJECT_LOGO           = ../../Api.WebService/devhelp/logo_Proj.png
OUTPUT_DIRECTORY       = ../DocFiles
SUBGROUPING            = NO
EXTRACT_PACKAGE        = YES
EXTRACT_STATIC         = YES
HIDE_UNDOC_MEMBERS     = YES
HIDE_UNDOC_CLASSES     = YES
SHOW_INCLUDE_FILES     = NO
SHOW_USED_FILES        = NO
SHOW_FILES             = NO
INPUT                  = ../../Api
FILE_PATTERNS          = *.c \x
                         *.cc \
                         *.cxx \
                         *.cpp \
                         *.c++ \
                         *.d \
                         *.java \
                         *.ii \
                         *.ixx \
                         *.ipp \
                         *.i++ \
                         *.inl \
                         *.h \
                         *.hh \
                         *.hxx \
                         *.hpp \
                         *.h++ \
                         *.idl \
                         *.odl \
                         *.cs \
                         *.php \
                         *.php3 \
                         *.inc \
                         *.m \
                         *.markdown \
                         *.md \
                         *.mm \
                         *.dox \
                         *.py \
                         *.f90 \
                         *.f \
                         *.for \
                         *.vhd \
                         *.vhdl
RECURSIVE              = YES
EXCLUDE                = ../../Api/XmlSerialization.cs
EXCLUDE_PATTERNS       = *Service.cs \
                         *Plugin.cs \
                         *Validation/* \
                         *Filters/*
USE_MDFILE_AS_MAINPAGE = readme.md
HTML_OUTPUT            = docs
HTML_COLORSTYLE_HUE    = 354
HTML_TIMESTAMP         = YES
HTML_DYNAMIC_SECTIONS  = YES
ENUM_VALUES_PER_LINE   = 1
MATHJAX_RELPATH        = http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest
GENERATE_LATEX         = NO
LATEX_CMD_NAME         = latex
RTF_HYPERLINKS         = YES
```

Thanks

Comment: Looks like the comment is incorrect should be `///` i.e. three slashes

Comment: Yesterday I misread a bit the question. I now created the case as above and I don't see just a main page. I used version 1.8.14 (current version is 1.8.15! but I don't have that version at hand ) and the current head and in both cases I only got a main page and nothing else. Which version are you using ? If not 1.8.15 please update to this version and retest when using 1.8.15 run `doxygen -x´ and post the results.

Comment: I get just the page for Foo but with bar showing up as one of its properties. My impression was that with HIDE_UNDOC_MEMBERS set to YES it would be hidden from the Foo documentation due to the // @cond Beta set in the Bar class.

Comment: Also tried it with three slashes as /// @cond Beta but it did not change the result.

Comment: I tried with the provided changes in the Doxyfile (I just undid the OUTPUT_DIRECTORY, HTML_OUTPUT and PROJECT_LOGO) but I still don't see the problems indicated (I used master and 1.8.14 as I don't have 1.8.15 at hand). Please try to create a small self contained example that shows the problem and post it here or create an issue in the doxygen issue tracker (https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/new) with attached a, small, self contained example (source+config file in a tar or zip) that allows us to reproduce the problem?  Please don't add external links as they might not be persistent.

Comment: I've posted here with the sample project and pic of the problem. https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/6898

Comment: I've also tested with version 1.8.14 with the same results